# Paging data from database and network in Flutter

Tags: flutter, paging

I'm pretty new to Flutter development, coming from an Android background. I want to implement the following [pattern](https://youtu.be/1cwqGOku2a4?t=296) like it is commenly used with the Paging 3 jetpack library:

```
UI <-------> Repo --- Out of data ---> Network
               ^                          |
               |                          |
               ---------- Save ------------
```

I also want to support paging in both directions. Anything I have seen so far on pub.dev is only paging in one direction. Do I have to implement this pattern for myself or is there already a library for this?

Comment: please try to check https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_paging. However it is still under development if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is from a database via network, you could use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) to do network requests and [dio_http_cache](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache) to cache the data. With [forceRefresh option](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http_cache#:%7E:text=forceRefresh%3A%20false%20default.) enabled, user would see the cached data when they don't have internet access and see fresh data when they have internet access.

This is the closest at this time to what you need.